# How to send email in OCaml, with setting `Content-Type: Multipart/Alternative`

Tags: ocaml

I want to send email via my own OCaml code.

The email will be in HTML format, so the `MIME` will be `Content-Type: Multipart/Alternative`.

In my server, the email smtp server is setup by myself and remains private, which means, I don't need any authentication, or whatsoever. Potentially my ocaml code can just connect and send the html email.

---

**My question is how to write this sending email code in OCaml? and what library should I use?**

---

I have considered `Netsmtp` from `OCamlNet` (http://docs.camlcity.org/docs/godipkg/4.00/godi-ocamlnet/lib/ocaml/pkg-lib/smtp/netsmtp.mli), but it seems cannot let me set the `MIME` to be `Content-Type: Multipart/Alternative`.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Ocamlnet/NetSendMail

```
let s_html = "<html>...</html>";;

let body = (Netsendmail.wrap_attachment ~content_type:("text/html", [])
                                        (new Netmime.memory_mime_body s_html))::[];;

let email = Netsendmail.wrap_mail
        ~from_addr:fa
        ~to_addrs:ta
        ~out_charset:`Enc_utf8
        ~subject:subject
               (
                Netsendmail.wrap_parts 
                ~content_type:("multipart/mixed",[])
                body);;

 Netsendmail.sendmail ~mailer:"/usr/sbin/sendmail" email;;
```

You can add separate parts :

```
let add_part other_parts =  (Netsendmail.wrap_parts ~content_type:("multipart/mixed",[]))@other_parts
```

Comment: It's the work of sendmail. It's a little bit difficult ton configure, I can say...

Comment: I used your code, it is very good. But sometimes I get such an error: `Unix.Unix_error(Unix.ENOMEM, "fork", "")`, why?

Comment: @Ontologiae Do you know a quick way to configure sendmail so that its messages don't get flagged as spam?

Answer (score 0):

In SMTP protocol, the body and header of the message is sent with the DATA command, so you can forge the header and the body in the same string, and send them with the data command using Netsmtp library.

```
let email_header = "\
From: John <john@example.com>\r\n\
To: Rob <rob@example.com>\r\n\
Subject: Hello\r\n\
Content-Type: Multipart/Alternative" in
let email_msg = "<h1>Hi Rob</h1>" in
let data = email_header ^ "\r\n\r\n" ^ email_msg;
```

Comment: do you know how to use OCamlNet's smtp?